# How would I use ASP.NET MVC to read posts to our Facebook Page and post on Web Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

Most of the information I am finding on this is older than the newer version of Facebook API, and I really don't know my way around the Facebook API.

Searching the developer section now seems to be mostly centered on their newer AI technologies, but I am simply interested in learning how to read from our Page's feed. Posting to our feed would be nice, too, but that would be down the line.

Actually, I just want the latest 4 or 5 posts to our Facebook Page to give the website a current look and feel.

I'm looking for documentation on how to read from our Facebook Page using API like calls with ASP.NET MVC 5 (sorry, but I have not had experience with ASP.NET Core yet).

Some short example code on how I'd make such a call would be fantastic.

Comment: The endpoint for the page feed is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v15.0/page/feed And you'll probably have to read up on some API basics as well, stuff like how authentication works etc., https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the page feed document from Facebook ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v16.0/page/feed))on how to get a page feed. You need decide what you need as result from this page feed api and add/remove fields into your FacebookPageData classs accordingly. I recommend to use Facebook graph explorer read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/explorer#get-token-dropdown) and try it out to see what data you are getting back.

You will need an access token to authenticate your request read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#get-a-page-access-token). This is a [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) to access token debuger tool from Facebook.

I am showing you a sample code on how to get a page feed from the ASP.Net MVC controller but you need to pick what is best for you.

**Sample Page Access token class**

```
public class FaceBookPageAccessToken 
{
    public string access_token {get;set;} //pageaccesstoken
    public string id {get; set;} //pageId
}
```

**Sample Page data class**

```
public class FacebookPageData
{
    public string id {get;set;}

    public string message {get;set;}

    public string created_time {get;set;}
    //public bool is_published {get;set;}


}
```

**Sample ASP.Net MVC Controller code , you can modified it based on your return type or usecase.**

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> GetFaceBookPageData()
    {

            var faceBookPageId = "YOUR-PAGE-ID"; // Replace with your facebook page id.
            var faceBookUserAccessToken = "abcdefgh123456"; // replace with your facbook user access token
            var facbookUserId ="YOUR-Facebook-UserId"; // replace with your facebook user id with read/manage(page_show_list) permission on page. 
            string baseApiUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/";
            string apiUrl = baseApiUrl+faceBookPageId+"/feed?access_token="+ faceBookUserAccessToken;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
             //Get the FaceBookPage Access token first.
            // //HTTP GET to get Page access token 
            // client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/"+faceBookPageId+"?fields=access_token&access_token="+ faceBookUserAccessToken);

            // var responseTask = client.GetAsync("product");
            // responseTask.Wait();
            // var result = responseTask.Result;
            // if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            // {
            //     var facbookPageAccessToken = result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<FaceBookPageAccessToken>();

            //     // Get Response JSON
            //     // {
            //     // "access_token":"PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN",
            //     // "id":"PAGE-ID"              
            //     // }
            // }
           
            
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseApiUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")
            );
          

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readPageData = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IList<FacebookPageData>>();

                // you can return JSON Data the way you want to view from here.

                var result = from d in readPageData
                             select new[]
                            {
                                d.id,
                                Convert.ToString(d.created_time),
                                d.message,
                             };
            
            }
            else
            {
                // web api sent error response
                //error handling code
            }          
            }

           
        
    }


}
```

**Sample JSON Response of Page Feed data**

[image]

**Sample JSON Response from Page Acess Token**

[image]